# Как мне поискать версию Symfony фреймворк без дололнений?

Tags: php, symfony, framework

Вопрос такой: как найти версию Симфони 4, которая будет без дополнений? То что я скачал сейчас это блог и интернет магазин. У меня есть книга по этому фреймворку и я хотел изучить его. Ссылки из книги не рабочие, Яшка и Гугл даёт ответы с уже готовыми приложениями (как я и скачал в первый раз). В общем не могу найти. Подскажите пожалуйста где скачать? Ещё проблема в том, что в книге обсуждается 2 версия, а сейчас... 4 по-моему? Отличаются эти версии многим и хотелось бы в крадце узнать чем?

Comment: Книгу по симфони2 можно смело откладывать. Тем более что любые версии симфони2 __официально__ более не поддерживаются.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте обычный "скелет" проекта. [Документация symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)

Создастся стандартная иерархия папок. Дальше можете добавлять код по вкусу

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

> Отличаются эти версии многим и хотелось бы в крадце узнать чем?

Структурой проекта, структурой конфигов, способом установки пакетов и т.д. Переход с версии на версию обычно сопряжен с массой дополнительных действий по миграции. Поэтому, если только начинаете изучать, то изучайте с 4-й

Масса уроков есть у самой symfony [SymfonyCasts](https://symfonycasts.com/) Некоторые видео только по платной подписке, зато текст и примеры бесплатно